# Pandas filter without ~ and not in operator

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes like as below

```
ID,Name,Sub,Country
1,ABC,ENG,UK
1,ABC,MATHS,UK
1,ABC,Science,UK
2,ABE,ENG,USA
2,ABE,MATHS,USA
2,ABE,Science,USA
3,ABF,ENG,IND
3,ABF,MATHS,IND
3,ABF,Science,IND

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

ID,Name,class,age
11,ABC,ENG,21
12,ABC,MATHS,23
1,ABC,Science,25
22,ABE,ENG,19
23,ABE,MATHS,22
24,ABE,Science,26
33,ABF,ENG,24
31,ABF,MATHS,28
32,ABF,Science,26

df2 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to do the below

a) Check whether the `ID` and `Name` from `df1` is present in `df2`.

b) If present in `df2`, put `Yes` in Status column or `No` in Status column. Don't use `~` or `not in` operator because my df2 has million of rows. So, it will result in irrelevant results

I tried the below

```
ID_list = df1['ID'].unique().tolist()
Name_list = df1['Name'].unique().tolist()
filtered_df = df2[((df2['ID'].isin(ID_list)) & (df2['Name'].isin(Name_list)))]
filtered_df = filtered_df.groupby(['ID','Name','Sub']).size().reset_index()
```

The above code gives matching ids and names between `df1` and `df2`.

But I want to find the `ids` and `names` that are present in `df1` but missing/absent in `df2`. **I cannot use the `~` operator because it will return all the rows from `df2` that don't have a match in `df1`. In real world, my df2 has millions of rows. I only want to find the `missing df1 ids and names and put a status column`**

I expect my output to be like as below

```
ID,Name,Sub,Country, Status
1,ABC,ENG,UK,No
1,ABC,MATHS,UK,No
1,ABC,Science,UK,Yes
2,ABE,ENG,USA,No
2,ABE,MATHS,USA,No
2,ABE,Science,USA,No
3,ABF,ENG,IND,No
3,ABF,MATHS,IND,No
3,ABF,Science,IND,No
```

Comment: There's "set" functionality on `pandas.Index` so you could convert the relevant series to Index objects and use that.  Eg https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected ouput is for match by 3 columns:

```
m = df1.merge(df2, 
              left_on=['ID','Name','Sub'],
              right_on=['ID','Name','class'], 
              indicator=True, how='left')['_merge'].eq('both')
df1['Status'] = np.where(m, 'Yes', 'No')
print (df1)
   ID Name      Sub Country Status
0   1  ABC      ENG      UK     No
1   1  ABC    MATHS      UK     No
2   1  ABC  Science      UK    Yes
3   2  ABE      ENG     USA     No
4   2  ABE    MATHS     USA     No
5   2  ABE  Science     USA     No
6   3  ABF      ENG     IND     No
7   3  ABF    MATHS     IND     No
8   3  ABF  Science     IND     No
```

With testing by `isin` solution is:

```
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1[['ID','Name','Sub']])
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2[['ID','Name','class']]) 
df1['Status'] = np.where(idx1.isin(idx2), 'Yes', 'No')
print (df1)
   ID Name      Sub Country Status
0   1  ABC      ENG      UK     No
1   1  ABC    MATHS      UK     No
2   1  ABC  Science      UK    Yes
3   2  ABE      ENG     USA     No
4   2  ABE    MATHS     USA     No
5   2  ABE  Science     USA     No
6   3  ABF      ENG     IND     No
7   3  ABF    MATHS     IND     No
8   3  ABF  Science     IND     No
```

Because if match by 2 columns ouput is different:

```
m = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID','Name'], indicator=True, how='left')['_merge'].eq('both')
df1['Status'] = np.where(m, 'Yes', 'No')
print (df1)
   ID Name      Sub Country Status
0   1  ABC      ENG      UK    Yes
1   1  ABC    MATHS      UK    Yes
2   1  ABC  Science      UK    Yes
3   2  ABE      ENG     USA     No
4   2  ABE    MATHS     USA     No
5   2  ABE  Science     USA     No
6   3  ABF      ENG     IND     No
7   3  ABF    MATHS     IND     No
8   3  ABF  Science     IND     No
```